# Akka committableOffset store in DB

Tags: scala, akka

I am beginner in `akka` and I have an problem statement to work with. I have an  `akka flow`  that's reading `Kafka Events` from some topic and doing some `transformation` before creating `Commitable offset of the message`.

I am not sure the best way to add a `akka sink` on top of this code to store the `transformed events` in some DB

```
def eventTransform : Flow[KafkaMessage,CommittableRecord[Either[Throwable,SomeEvent]],NotUsed]

def processEvents
      : Flow[KafkaMessage, ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset, NotUsed] =
    Flow[KafkaMessage]
      .via(eventTransform) 
      .filter({ x =>
        x.value match {
          case Right(event: SomeEvent) =>
            event.status != "running"
          case Left(_) => false
        }
      })

      .map(_.message.committableOffset)
```

This is my `akka source` calling the `akka flow`

```
private val consumerSettings: ConsumerSettings[String, String] = ConsumerSettings(
    system,
    new StringDeserializer,
    new StringDeserializer,
  )
    .withGroupId(groupId)
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

  private val committerSettings: CommitterSettings = CommitterSettings(system)
  private val control = new AtomicReference[Consumer.Control](Consumer.NoopControl)

 

  private val restartableSource = RestartSource
    .withBackoff(restartSettings) { () =>
      Consumer
        .committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topicIn))
        .mapMaterializedValue(control.set)
        .via(processEvents) // calling the flow here
    }

  restartableSource
    .toMat(Committer.sink(committerSettings))(Keep.both)
    .run()

  def api(): Behavior[Message] =
    Behaviors.receive[Message] { (_, message) =>
      message match {
        case Stop =>
          context.pipeToSelf(control.get().shutdown())(_ => Stopped)
          Behaviors.same

        case Stopped =>
          Behaviors.stopped
      }
    }
      .receiveSignal {
        case (_, _ @(PostStop | PreRestart)) =>
          control.get().shutdown()
          Behaviors.same
      }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to filter some events? This way kafka messages corresponding to them are never committed. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes actually based on the filtered events , we need to perform some other operations. Thats what I am trying to do `runwith - akka sink` . But still now unable to

Comment: To store the events in the DB it would be best to create flow for the storing. With event on input, and something like (eventOffset, storageResult) on the output.

Comment: Not sure but as per `akka` documentation - this type of activity(after transformation storing data) should be part of `sink` right ?

Comment: No, it's not a strict rule, rather guideline, and it fits to transform->store scenario, but not so much to transform->store->commit. It is also possible to divide the flow into 2 sinks and store in one, and commit in another, but then the event is always commited even if storing it throws some exception or is unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you please guide me on the `flow` should be part of `processEvents method` only after the `filter`. Also not sure how in the `via` pass the `filtered` events only